# Arithmetic with Time in R

Tags: r

[image]

```
 dt$st<- substr(strptime(dt$LoginTime, format = "%H:%S"),12,20)
```

Using the above code I have extracted the time which is in Character Format,  I wish to do arithmetic on it. such as if I want to multiply a column of numbers with above column, how to i do it?

Structure of LoginTime Column is :

```
structure(c(1505L, 231L, 1606L, 757L, 139L, 702L), .Label = c("0:00:01", 
"0:00:05", "0:00:06", "0:00:07", "0:00:10", "0:00:12", "0:00:13", 9:56:01", 
"9:56:31", "9:57:11", "9:57:39", "9:58:37"), class = "factor")
```

Comment: Don't use `substr` and `strptime` for this. Convert your datetime to `POSIXlt` and extract what you need from that.

Comment: I got this error----dt$st<- as.POSIXlt(dt$LoginTime)
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(as.character(x), ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Comment: Add the output of `dput(head(dt$LoginTime))` to your question. A screenshot is useless.

Comment: I have attached the output above,Hope this helps

Comment: To what exactly you want to convert this column? to a Date or just to some number?

Comment: in excel you can take a time and multiply it with a number to get total time. This exactly what i am trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you can do some of the calculations with a small adjusment to your code. 
For example

To compute mean

```
substr(mean(strptime(dt$LoginTime, format = "%H:%S")), 12, 20)
```

To add 10 seconds to each row

```
substr(strptime(dt$LoginTime, format = "%H:%S") + 10, 12, 20)
```

To add a minute to each row

```
substr(strptime(dt$LoginTime, format = "%H:%S") + 60, 12, 20)
```

To add an hour

```
substr(strptime(dt$LoginTime, format = "%H:%S") + 3600, 12, 20)
```

To add two hours

```
substr(strptime(dt$LoginTime, format = "%H:%S") + 7200, 12, 20)
```

Comment: Thanks Dave for pointing that out, but it seems only + and - operations are allowed. * and hence / operations are NOT allowed.

Comment: After some thought, I think I am mistaken to think Hours exactly like time and in the end I only wish to multiply hours by a certain number to find total number of hours

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have periods and not times. You could use package lubridate:

```
x <- factor(c("0:00:13", "9:56:01"))

library(lubridate)
y <- hms(x)
#[1] "13S"       "9H 56M 1S"
```

However, read `help("period")`:

> Within a Period object, time units do not have a fixed length (except
>   for seconds) until they are added to a date-time. The length of each
>   time unit will depend on the date-time to which it is added. For
>   example, a year that begins on 2009-01-01 will be 365 days long. A
>   year that begins on 2012-01-01 will be 366 days long. When math is
>   performed with a period object, each unit is applied separately. How
>   the length of a period is distributed among its units is non-trivial.
>   For example, when leap seconds occur 1 minute is longer than 60
>   seconds.

```
y*3
#[1] "39S"         "27H 168M 3S"
```

Comment: This gives me a character string, but lets say I want to find the mean  of column (x), then how do i do it?